PCB design review (Altium)
I have recently designed my first PCB using Altium and I am seeking feedback on it.
the PCB stack-up is 4 layers (signal, GND, GND, signal).
The PCB includes various components such as a STM32, 3.3 V regulator (AP7313-33), Accelerometer and Gyroscope Module (MPU6050), USB, and external GPIO Pins (with TVS diodes for ESD protection).
Given that this is my first attempt at PCB design, I would appreciate any insights or suggestions from you to identify potential issues or improvements.


]


Two-sided assembly will push up costs, though it might be slightly better electrically for the bypass caps. You look to have more than enough room to put everything on one side.

USB shield is open?

I believe most (all?) STM32 only need a 5 pin SWD interface. Supply, GND, reset, SWDIO, SWDCLK.

It is good to add fiducial points. Helps assembling.

Have you considered Vcc on layer 3 instead of ground?

If Vcc is a plane, it would remove several of your traces. Moreover, to minimize crosstalk and keep the copper balanced, do ground pour on top layer and stitch all islands with vias to layer 2. You could consider pouring bottom layer with Vcc in the same manner.

You have 12 I/O pins with protection. You could consider using more appropriate USBLC6-4 x 3 and 4-resistor networks x 3, thus reducing the parts count by 18 with improved protection.

The quality of the schematics image is not great, therefore I can't read part numbers, but:

Check that there is no required pull-up on NRST.
All the part on the same side is easier to build.
Check the clearance between your top right mounting hole and the programming connector. The hole may be fine, but have you checked that a standard screw head won't touch the connector?
it seems that you are using bidirectional TVS diodes to protect your PA pins. Because you don't expect negative voltages on that connector. Use diodes that will clamp negative voltage as soon as possible. Not diodes that start to conduct at -3.3V only (if I read the part number correctly). Unidirectional TVS diodes will already clamp at -0.6 ish. (but pay attention to put them in the right orientation...)
Put the linear dimensions of the board on the Mechanical 1 layers. Depending on how you export your manufacturing files, the unit may be lost. Having the dimensions (with the unit of course) on that layer is a way to ensure there is no misunderstanding with the PCB shop. This rarely occurs, but I have already experienced it.

